# How is the output of a contract call encoded?

Tags: solidity, evm, ethereumjs

Hi I have a proxy contract A which delegates function execution to implementation contract B using the standard OpenZeppelin code:

```
assembly {
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())


            let result := delegatecall(gas(), _implementation, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)

            // Copy the returned data.
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())

            switch result
            // delegatecall returns 0 on error.
            case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize()) }
            default { return(0, returndatasize()) }
        }
```

when I tried to call a function getter for a result which is supposed to be `[10, 100]` I got the string `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064`. What is this encoding and which library I can use to decode it. At first I thought it was RLP encoding but I checked with some RLP decoders but it didn't check out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ABI encoding format used by Solidity, which is documented in the [Contract ABI Specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/abi-spec.html). Basically, static values (e.g., numbers, booleans, bytes1..32) are encoded into 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters), and dynamic values are encoded at the end, where a pointer to the location is encoded in place instead.

Using your result as an example, first you split it up into groups of 32 bytes.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
```

Since the output is an array, the first 32 bytes (`0x000...020`) are the pointer to the array, in this case `0x20` or 32, meaning that the array is at position 32 in the output (which is in this case the next 32 bytes). This second group of 32 bytes specify the length of the array, in this case `0x2` or simply 2, meaning that the next two groups of 32 bytes are part of the array.

As expected, the last two groups, `0x0a` and `0x64` are 10 and 100 respectively, so decoding the output results in `[10, 100]` as expected.

Of course doing this by hand isn't very efficient, and there are libraries out there that can parse the output for you automatically. Assuming you're using JavaScript/TypeScript:

- `@ethersproject/abi` - https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js (part of Ethers.js)
- `web3-eth-abi` - https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/tree/1.x/packages/web3-eth-abi (part of Web3.js, but it uses `@ethersproject/abi` under the hood).
- `@findeth/abi` - https://github.com/findeth/abi

There are also some online tools which you can use to encode and decode:

- https://adibas03.github.io/online-ethereum-abi-encoder-decoder/
- https://abi.hashex.org/
- https://abi.sonnguyen.ws/

Comment: The output depends on the function return type. For example in this case it can also be interpreted as a tuple of four uint8.

Comment: I tried to use ethers.js as follows
```
ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode([`uint256`, `uint256`], output)
```
and got `[32,2]` instead of `[10, 100]`

Comment: `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint256','uint256'],[10,100])` gives the same result `[32,2]`

Comment: The array specifies the type for each parameter, so since the first parameter type is `uint256[]`, you want to specify it like `encodeParameters(['uint256[]'], ...)`.

Comment: I managed to solve it. My mistake was in type definition. I should have put `['uint256[]']` instead of `['uint256', 'uint256']`.